# Laravel RBAC (Role Based Access Control) Model Relationship

Tags: laravel, model, permissions, relationship, rbac

I'm making my own role based access control implementation and need some help on a relationship question.

I have a User, Group and a Permission model, there's a pivot table between User / Group and between Group / Permission. How would I most efficiently retrieve the Permission model through the User model?

Thank you.

Edit:

Relationship is as follows;

User belongsToMany Group
Group belongsToMany User

Group belongsToMany Permission
Permission belongsToMany Group

Comment: How did you describe the relationships ?

Comment: Casbin fulfills all your needs: https://github.com/php-casbin/laravel-authz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your `Pivot Tables` relations are as follows:

`Group <-> User` has `many-to-many`

`Group <-> Permission` has `many-to-many`

> How would I most efficiently retrieve the Permission model through the
>   User model

Since there is no direct relationship between `User` and `Permission` model but you can get all the permissions through `Group` model:

```php
$user = User::with('groups.permissions')->find(1);
```

This will give you the `User` model with all `Group` models and nested `Permission` models so to get permissions you may try:

```php
// Get a collection
$permissionsOfFirstGroup = $user->groups->first()->permissions;
```

```php
// Get a collection
$permissionsOfSecondGroup = $user->groups->get(1)->permissions;
```

To get all permissions from all the groups you may try this:

```php
$permissions = $user->groups->fetch('permissions');
```

This will return you a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` object (A Collection of `Permission` models).

There are other ways (Using joins) but depends on your need how you do it.

Comment: Quick additional question, might not be as quick to answer though;
How would I check to see if there exist a relationship between the user and the permission by permission id?

Comment: This is how I solved it but it feels like there's a smarter way; 

Group::has('users')->where('id', '=', $this->id)->has('permissions')->where('id', '=', $resource->id)->get();